# How to display .mp4 files only?

Tags: php

Good day experts!!

I am currently enhancing my treeview project but I am stack at displaying certain filetype only. I want to display only mp4 type of files in my Treeview. Below are the codes:

( Credits to the original codes of Treeview )

```
class TreeView
{
    private $root;
 
    public function __construct($path)
    {
        $this->root = $path;
    }
 
    public function getTree()
    {
        return $this->createStructure($this->root, true);
    }
 
    private function createStructure($directory, $root)
    {
        $structure = $root ? '<ul class="treeview">' : '<ul>';
 
        $nodes = $this->getNodes($directory);
        
        foreach ($nodes as $node) {
            
            $path = $directory.'/'.$node;
            if (is_dir($path) ) {
                $structure .= '<li class="treeview-folder"><p>';
                $structure .= '<details class="details-example"><summary><font size="5px">'.$node.'</font></summary>';
                $structure .= self::createStructure($path, false);
                $structure .= '</p></li>';
            } else {
                $path = str_replace($this->root.'/', null, $path);
                $structure .= '<p><li class="treeview-file">';
                $structure .= '<a href="movies/./'.$path.'"><font size="5px">'.$node.'</font></a>';
                $structure .= '</li></p>';
            }
        }
 
        return $structure.'</ul>';
    }

    private function getNodes($directory = null)
    {
        $folders = [];
        $files = [];
 
        $nodes = scandir($directory);

        foreach ($nodes as $node) {
            if (!$this->exclude($node)) {
                if (is_dir($directory.'/'.$node)) {
                    $folders[] = $node;
                } else {
                    $files[] = $node;
                }
            }
        }
 
        return array_merge($folders, $files);
    }
 
    private function exclude($filename)
    {
        return in_array($filename, ['.', '..', 'index.php', '.htaccess', '.DS_Store']);
    }
}

$treeView = new TreeView('movies/');
echo $treeView->getTree();
```

Comment: The above PHP will generate invalid HTML. `<p><li class="treeview-file">` should be the other way around - the same for the closing tag pair. a `P` is not a valid child of `ul` but it can be a child of `li`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could supply a `"whitelist"` of permissable file extensions ( only one in this instance ) as a second argument to the above class and compare the extensions of any discovered files to that whitelist and thus control which files are returned.

```
class TreeView {
    private $root;
    private $whitelist;
 
    public function __construct($path, $whitelist=array() ){
        $this->root = $path;
        $this->whitelist=$whitelist;
    }
 
    public function getTree(){
        return $this->createStructure($this->root, true);
    }
 
    private function createStructure($directory, $root){
        $structure = $root ? '<ul class="treeview">' : '<ul>';
 
        $nodes = $this->getNodes($directory);
        
        foreach ($nodes as $node) {
            
            $path = $directory.'/'.$node;
            if (is_dir($path) ) {
                $structure .= '<li class="treeview-folder"><p>';
                $structure .= '<details class="details-example"><summary><font size="5px">'.$node.'</font></summary>';
                $structure .= self::createStructure($path, false);
                $structure .= '</p></li>';
            } else {
                $path = str_replace($this->root.'/', null, $path);
                $structure .= '<li class="treeview-file"><p>';
                $structure .= '<a href="movies/./'.$path.'"><font size="5px">'.$node.'</font></a>';
                $structure .= '</p></li>';
            }
        }
 
        return $structure.'</ul>';
    }

    private function getNodes($directory = null){
        $folders = [];
        $files = [];
 
        $nodes = scandir($directory);

        foreach ($nodes as $node) {
            if (!$this->exclude($node)) {
                if (is_dir($directory.'/'.$node)) {
                    $folders[] = $node;
                } else {
                    # check the whitelist for the file extension
                    if( !empty( $this->whitelist ) ){
                        $ext=strtolower( pathinfo( $node, PATHINFO_EXTENSION ) );
                        if( in_array( $ext, $this->whitelist ) ) $files[] = $node;
                    }else{
                        $files[] = $node;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return array_merge($folders, $files);
    }
 
    private function exclude($filename){
        return in_array($filename, ['.', '..', 'index.php', '.htaccess', '.DS_Store']);
    }
}




$whitelist=array('mp4');
$treeView = new TreeView('movies/',$whitelist);
echo $treeView->getTree();
```

Comment: this is exactly what im looking for, sir Professor Abronsius!!! I really appreciate your help. Now my students in our local website in our school will not be confused in playing our videos!! ^_^. Thank you so much sir. God bless your sir.